# Unequal variance in R linear mixed model post-hoc lsmeans issue

Tags: r, variance, nlme, lsmeans, multcompview

I fitted a linear mixed model to agricultural data, accounting for unequal variances across groups (cultivars) by passing `weights = varIdent(...)` to  `lme`. `lsmeans` is showing standard errors that do not align with significant differences.

An example of my code is below. Data to reproduce the output can be found [here](https://github.com/aikendall/Hedging-Code).

```
library(nlme)
library(multcomp)
library(emmeans)

model <- lme(variable ~ cultivar*year, 
             random = ~1|block, 
             weights = varIdent(form = ~1|cultivar),  
             method = "REML", 
             na.action = na.omit, 
             data = ag.data)

Leastsquare <- lsmeans(model,"cultivar")
cld(Leastsquare, Letters = letters)
```

```
 cultivar  lsmean     SE df lower.CL upper.CL .group
 Golden      6.92  3.841  1    -41.9     55.7  a    
 Campfield  10.33  4.330  1    -44.7     65.4  a    
 Tom        17.50  0.167  1     15.4     19.6  a    
 Harrison   25.67 12.649  1   -135.1    186.4  ab   
 Puget      30.58 20.502  1   -229.9    291.1  ab   
 HVC        37.08  5.331  1    -30.7    104.8   b   
 COL        38.08  0.433  1     32.6     43.6   b   
 Brown      62.67 20.207  1   -194.1    319.4  ab
```

How can it be that the the cultivar `Brown` is not significantly different from `Golden`? Is this acceptable? Has anyone seen results similar to this?

Comment: Why should it be?

Comment: I am unaccustomed to seeing the extreme values not be statistically different from one another when the intermediate values are, as the standard errors are far from overlapping (though I know that's not necessarily a requisite). As a disclaimer - I am a graduate student who is relatively new to this type of statistical analysis. Are you saying that these means separations are generally acceptable, for instance, for a peer-reviewed publication?

Comment: Understood. But imagine an extreme case where you have means of 1,2,3,4, SDs of 3,1,1,3, and sample sizes of 2,1000000,1000000,2 respectively. Since you have so much data on the inner two means, the inner two means are statistically different, and the outer two means are not because you have so little data and the SDs are larger. If you look at the SE of your highest mean, it is quite large and it is hard to distinguish it from the other means.

Answer (score 0):

I made your example into a [reprex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/). Please find my comments below.

```r
library(tidyverse)

ag.data <- tibble::tribble(
       ~year,   ~cultivar, ~block,   ~variable,
  "nineteen",       "HVC",     1L, 14.33333333,
  "nineteen",       "HVC",     2L, 23.33333333,
  "nineteen",     "Puget",     1L, 2.333333333,
  "nineteen",     "Puget",     2L, 3.333333333,
  "nineteen", "Campfield",     1L,          NA,
  "nineteen", "Campfield",     2L,           4,
  "nineteen",       "Tom",     1L,          10,
  "nineteen",       "Tom",     2L,          10,
  "nineteen",     "Brown",     1L,          NA,
  "nineteen",     "Brown",     2L, 56.66666667,
  "nineteen",       "COL",     1L,          NA,
  "nineteen",       "COL",     2L, 51.66666667,
  "nineteen",    "Golden",     1L,           5,
  "nineteen",    "Golden",     2L, 1.666666667,
  "nineteen",  "Harrison",     1L, 52.33333333,
  "nineteen",  "Harrison",     2L, 4.333333333,
    "twenty",       "HVC",     1L, 45.66666667,
    "twenty",       "HVC",     2L,          65,
    "twenty",     "Puget",     1L, 17.33333333,
    "twenty",     "Puget",     2L, 99.33333333,
    "twenty", "Campfield",     1L, 11.66666667,
    "twenty", "Campfield",     2L, 21.66666667,
    "twenty",       "Tom",     1L, 25.33333333,
    "twenty",       "Tom",     2L, 24.66666667,
    "twenty",     "Brown",     1L, 45.33333333,
    "twenty",     "Brown",     2L,          92,
    "twenty",       "COL",     1L,          24,
    "twenty",       "COL",     2L,          25,
    "twenty",    "Golden",     1L,           3,
    "twenty",    "Golden",     2L,          18,
    "twenty",  "Harrison",     1L,          31,
    "twenty",  "Harrison",     2L,          15
  )

library(nlme)
library(emmeans)
library(multcomp)
library(multcompView)

model <- lme(
  variable ~ cultivar * year,
  random = ~ 1 | block,
  weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | cultivar),
  method = "REML",
  na.action = na.omit,
  data = ag.data
)

anova(model)
#>               numDF denDF   F-value p-value
#> (Intercept)       1    12 16502.874  <.0001
#> cultivar          7    12   193.823  <.0001
#> year              1    12   952.713  <.0001
#> cultivar:year     7    12   296.145  <.0001

ag.data %>%
  filter(!is.na(variable)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = variable, x = year)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(cultivar)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_summary(fun = mean,
               color = "red",
               geom = "line",
               aes(group = 1)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

```r
emm <- emmeans(model, ~ cultivar) %>% 
  cld(Letters = letters) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(cultivar = fct_reorder(cultivar, emmean))
#> NOTE: Results may be misleading due to involvement in interactions

ggplot(emm, aes(
  y = emmean,
  ymin = lower.CL,
  ymax = upper.CL,
  x = cultivar,
  label = str_trim(.group)
)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.1) +
  geom_text(
    position = position_nudge(x = 0.1),
    hjust = 0,
    color = "red"
  ) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Addressing your question why the cultivars with the lowest and highest emmeans are not significantly different: I think looking at the second plot makes it clear that this is due to the vastly different precisions with which the emmeans were estimated. This in turn is in part due to the heterogeneous error variances you allowed in the model and also due to the missing/unbalanced data.
I would argue that you are "unaccustomed to seeing the extreme values not be statistically different from one another when the intermediate values are" because usually with balanced data and/or no heterogeneous error variance you would not. Try running the code without the `weights =` argument (i.e. with standard homogeneous error variance) - you will not find the "issue" you are having with these results.

Further note that you actually seem to be having cultivar-year-interactions - see the `anova()` and the first plot. Thus, looking at the cultivar means may be misleading as the note below the `emmeans()` function says. Instead, you could try investigating emmean-comparisons per year via `emmeans(~ cultivar|year)`.